# How to get footnote text with elsarticle at the bottom of a table?

Tags: tables, footnotes, elsarticle

I am trying to place footnotes at the bottom end of a table as shown in figure with elsarticle, but so far I am not successful.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Row sub numbering}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
S. No. & X & Y  & Z \\
\midrule
1      & 1 & 12 & 1 \\
2      & 4 & 34 & 3 \\
3      & 5 & 54 & 2\tnoteref{t1} \\
4      & 1 & 44 & 7 \\
5      & 4 & 11 & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\tnotetext[t1]{Footnote}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

With the MWE I am able to get the footnote symbol, but the footnote text does not appear. How to get footnote text with elsarticle at the bottom of a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can't obtain a table note: `\tnoteref` and `\tnotetext` are commands defined in the `elsarticle` class, not for *table* notes, but for *title* notes.

To have foot notes at the bottom of tables, use the `threeparttable` package. I suggest to use  `alphabetic` numbering of these footnotes – this will be less confusional in a table with numbers, and will not disrupt the system of ‘normal’ footnotes.

Should you need to cross-reference these table footnotes, you should use the `threeparttablex`, and extension of `threeparttable` to `longtable`, at the cost of a slightly different syntax.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Row sub numbering}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
      \toprule
      S. No. & X & Y & Z \\
      \midrule
      1 & 1 & 12 & 1 \\
      2 & 4 & 34 & 3 \\
      3 & 5 & 54 & 2\tnote{a} \\
      4 & 1 & 44 & 7 \\
      5 & 4 & 11 & 4 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[a]{Footnote}
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]